# How to validate a float number against format specifier?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to validate a user input against format specifier.For example format specifiers %4.5f , %4f , %10.5f, etc., If i specify %5.2f as format specifier I should able to validate user input whether its satisfies the given format %5.2f or not?

Note : I am using C++ in windows environment.

Comment: Sounds more like string matching than numeric stuff to me. How about a regular expression? If you're modern, there's the std `<regex>` header that should get you on your way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kerrek. Its Good idea to use regular expressions. So do i need to write regular expression for each and every format string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to do string matching against a regular expression. The expression should be:

```
[0-9]{n}\.[0-9]{m}
```

Here *n* and *m* are the number of digits to want. You can build a regular expression from a string, so just make the pattern string from your parameters and then construct the regex; it's all in `<regex>` on C++0x compilers (or `<tr1/regex>` otherwise).

Be careful to either match the entire input string or surround the expression by word boundaries to avoid 12345.67890 matching against m=2, n=2 as "45.67".

---

*Edit:* Here's one approach:

```
std::regex make_pattern(size_t m, size_t n)
{
  std::ostringstream ss;
  ss << "\b([0-9]{" << std::dec << m << "}\\.[0-9]{" << n << "})\b";
  return std::regex(ss.str());
}

/* later */

std::regex rx = make_pattern(4, 5);
std::string input = get_input();
const bool is_valid = std::regex_match(input, rx);
```

Comment: you could also use a similar method to make your format strings

Comment: `boost::regex` library is an alternative

Comment: This regeular expression is not well formed ; please anyone help me to form regular expression for the above requirement.

Comment: @Rajesh: Whoops, I forgot the closing parenthesis around the capture group, fixed now. In my written example I added a capture group so you can actually extract the matching number in case you allow ambient whitespaces etc.

Comment: Here is another pattern which works for me.                         td::regex make_pattern(size_t m, size_t n)
{
  std::ostringstream ss;
  ss << "^[0-9]{0,"<<std::dec<<m<<"}\\.[0-9]{0,"<<std::dec<<n<<"}$;
  return std::regex(ss.str());
}

Comment: @Rajesh: Yes yes, the round parentheses are completely optional -- I just put them in in case you later want to refer to the actual match (that's called a "capture group"). If you don't need that you can omit them. Oh, good catch on the backslash!! I'll edit that too.